# JSFiddle Function not working

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

My JSFiddle function is not working, The function `getAllLocations` when the button is clicked does not get executed. Your help is appreaciated.

**The HTML**

```
<div id="map" style="width: 800px; height:500px" align="center"></div>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="getAllLocations();">GET ALL THE LOCATIONS</button>

    <div>
        <h3>Output Console</h3>

        <textarea id="TextArea" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
        <br>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([ 10.88869, 10.85878 ], 18);

        L.tileLayer(
                        'https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                        {
                            maxZoom : 20,
                            attribution : 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, '
                                    + '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, '
                                    + 'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
                            id : 'examples.map-i86knfo3'
                        }).addTo(map);

        var poly = L.polyline([], {
            color : 'green'
        });
        poly.addTo(map);

        map.on('click', function(e) {
            poly.addLatLng(e.latlng);

            //alert();
        });

        function getAllLocations(){
            alert ("Test");
            var locArray = poly.getLatLngs();
            var area = document.getElementById('TextArea');

            for(var i=0; i<locArray.length; i++){

                var item2 = locArray[i];
                var item3 = "" + item2;
                var item4 = item3.split("(");
                var item5 = item4[1].split(")")
                //alert(item5[0]);

                area.value += item5[0] + "\n";


            }
        }
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdLrb/7/)

Comment: Change your JSFiddle to place script in head http://jsfiddle.net/ZdLrb/9/

Comment: L is not defined (JS error), which prevents the rest of the code from running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your <s>context is being changed</s> function is going out of scope.
Define your function like this and it will work so that the function is global.

```
getAllLocations = function (){
alert ("Test");
    var locArray = poly.getLatLngs();
    var area = document.getElementById('TextArea');

    for(var i=0; i<locArray.length; i++){

        var item2 = locArray[i];
        var item3 = "" + item2;
        var item4 = item3.split("(");
        var item5 = item4[1].split(")")
        //alert(item5[0]);

        area.value += item5[0] + "\n";


    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks for the Answer :)
Can you kindly explain me what do you mean by context is being changed?

Comment: The context is essentially what the value of `this` is. It actually turns out I was mistaken, the context is the same for your fiddle but as you have it running onload this means your javascript is wrapped in an onload function so your function won't be global by default, it would only be available within the onload function.

Answer (score 0):

I have commented your question with this. There are still issues in your code but it will run on jSFiddle (include script in head)

You'll get these errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Map container not found. leaflet.js:6
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLatLngs' of undefined
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdLrb/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition is OK actually. YOu just need to change the `LOAD TYPE`setting. Like this... [screenshot:load type setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpixd.png)

Your script was being wrapped within onLoad, `getAllLocations` was not global. Setting to `no wrap` allows it to be defined on the global scope.